# Fitting Variance Gamma distribution to the data

Tags: optimization

```
x<-c(1291,849,238,140,118,108,87,70,63,58,50,47,21,21,19)
library(VarianceGamma)
init<-c(0,0.5,0,0.5)
vgFit(x, freq = NULL, breaks = NULL, paramStart = init, startMethod = "Nelder-Mead", startValues = "SL", method = "Nelder-Mead", hessian = FALSE, plots = TRUE)
```

I want to fit the data,but it shows the error.

```
Error in optim(paramStart, llfunc, NULL, method = "Nelder-Mead", hessian = hessian,  : 

  function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters.
```

I do not know what the error means, because I use the initial value that can be used in the VG distribution pdf.
  I have surfed the Internet , somebody said it may be have zero point and can not be minimized in r.